# scp checks existence in the wrong order

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, scp

I've just come across a what I think is an odd behavior in scp. Consider the following:

```
root@box:~$ scp foo.txt root@example.com:
root@example.com's password:
foo.txt: No such file or directory
```

I find it odd that I didn't get the no such file error before logging in to the remote server so, **Is this a bug and if not why is this behavior desireable?**

I'm running openssh-client version 1:6.7p1-5 on Debian Jessie.

Comment: scp's primary purpose is not to validate the existence of files, but rather secure file transfer, so it makes sense that it prioritizes making a secure connection, before file operations.  I would recommend reading the RFC for SSH for a fuller understanding of the technical details of the protocol and it's reasons for working as it does.

Comment: I think this is mainly a code efficiency issue actually. For this behavior to change scp would need to check if the file exists before creating the connection. When the connection is made there is still a chance that the file was already deleted. This means that a check before connecting is actually not needed. From a user experience point it might make sense to do it anyway....

Comment: @Paul Many thanks, that makes sense. Could you put that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is mainly a code efficiency issue actually. For this behavior to change scp would need to check if the file exists before creating the connection. When the connection is made there is still a chance that the file was already deleted. This means that a check before connecting is actually not needed. From a user experience point it might make sense to do it anyway....